# Create Edges by ETL in same Class

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

1) Class Items with ItemId and Name ready in the database.
2) CSV-file: two columns,

```
ItemId1,ItemId2001

ItemId1,ItemId2345

ItemId1,ItemId2381
```

...

```
ItemId2,ItemId8393

ItemId2,ItemId8743
```

..
etc.

Question:

How to define a ETL json-file to create Edges between ItemId1 and all the ItemId's in col#2, and between ItemId2 and its col#2-peers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem.

I had this Items

[image]

and with this code I connected them

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "myPath/item.csv" } },
  "extractor": {"row": {}},
    "transformers": [{
        "csv": {
            "separator": ","
        }
    },
    {
    "command" : {
            "command" : "create edge from (select from Item where idItem= '${input.idItem1}') to (select from Item where idItem= '${input.idItem2}')",
            "output" : "edge"
        }
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:myPath/myDb",
       "dbType": "graph"
    }
  }
}
```

and I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can a "unresolvedLinkAction" be added here? In case yes, where?

Comment: I don't think is possible. Reading the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Transformer.html it seems that you can use it only with merge and edge transformer, not with the command

Comment: This procedure ran wild creating millions of edges. Adding entry in Issue tracker.

Comment: Not an issue. The key thing is duplicate keys in the select from. Need @rid to make the source vertex unique.